# Using existing data for primary key and then creating additional rows APEX 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table in Excel that includes a primary key column called id.  I want to keep the existing id column and then automatically create new sequence that begins where the old one stops.  I was able to import the data without a problem, but can't figure out how to add the new sequence/trigger in Oracle APEX 5.

Example Columns

```
id  1, 2, ....250

company_name ABC Corporation, DEF Corporation, etc.
```

I want to keep all the id data for the first 250 rows and then be able to add new rows where it automatically creates a new id, beginning at 251